# Screen transition effects android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I am trying left to right swipe transition of button click in screen one and right to left transition from screen 2 to screen one. The following is the codes

Screen 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActivityTransitionActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
startActivity(intent);
```

Screen 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, CustomActivityTransitionActivity.class);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
startActivity(intent);
```

The respective anims are give below,

Slide_in_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Slide_out_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Slide_in_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Slide_out_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

It is giving some top transition, however if i use only one say from left to right swipe and disable right to left, its working. Please guide where i am going wrong with what values to replace.

Comment: Are you sure that percentage values are working with animations? I might be wrong but always thought they had to be pixel values. Also you might want to move your ``overridePendingTransition`` call after you have called ``startActivity`` already. Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried android's default animation android.R.anim.slide_in_left?

Comment: Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish()

Comment: @wangyif2, thanks fro that, used it and its working, @ Anand, yup, now put it at the top and working, thanks for your comments!!